# How to split a multivalued tag into small XMLs using groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy

Good morning Dear,

I have the following scenario:

I have an XML in which the Filter tag has many values for the ActivityObjectId field as an example below:

And ActivityCodeTypeName IN('SAP Network','SAP Activity','SAP Transfer','SAP WBS Costs','SAP Transfer (PEP)')</v1:Filter>

In this example the ActivityObjectId field has 13 values

I need to break the Filter tag into blocks containing 5 values for the ActivityObjectId field

Output:

```
<v1:Filter>ActivityObjectId IN (6507036,6507037,6507038,6507039,6507040)
                     AND ActivityCodeTypeName IN ('SAP Network','SAP Activity','SAP Transfer','SAP WBS Costs','SAP Transfer (PEP)')</v1:Filter>

<v1:Filter>ActivityObjectId IN (6507041,6507042,6507043,6507044,6507045)
                     AND ActivityCodeTypeName IN ('SAP Network','SAP Activity','SAP Transfer','SAP WBS Costs','SAP Transfer (PEP)')</v1:Filter>

<v1:Filter>ActivityObjectId IN (6507046,6507047,6507048)
                     AND ActivityCodeTypeName IN ('SAP Network','SAP Activity','SAP Transfer','SAP WBS Costs','SAP Transfer (PEP)')</v1:Filter>
```

Remembering that the ActivityObjectId field can receive n values.

How do I do this using groovy script?
Could you help me?

Here is the complete XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.XXXX.com/YY/X6/WS/ActivityCodeAssignment/V1">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-d0ce0b7b-c4b2-416c-b2dc-ac95015ffcb9">
            <wsu:Created>2023-06-27T18:30:28.298Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2023-06-28T11:10:28.298Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-d3376a72-8584-4a4c-8929-c84c710ea7eb">
            <wsse:Username>XXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXX</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">AAAA</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2023-06-27T18:30:28.298Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:ReadActivityCodeAssignments>
         <v1:Field>ActivityCodeObjectId</v1:Field>
         <v1:Field>ActivityObjectId</v1:Field>
         <v1:Field>ActivityCodeValue</v1:Field>
         <v1:Field>ActivityCodeTypeName</v1:Field>
         <v1:Field>ActivityCodeTypeObjectId</v1:Field>
         <v1:Filter>ActivityObjectId IN  (6507036,6507037,6507038,6507039,6507040,6507041,6507042,6507043,6507044,6507045,6507046,6507047,6507048)
                    AND ActivityCodeTypeName IN ('SAP Network','SAP Activity','SAP Transfer','SAP WBS Custos','SAP Transfer (PEP)')</v1:Filter>
      </v1:ReadActivityCodeAssignments>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Output would not be a well formed xml since output would be an array as the root node.  Also the namespace vi would not be defined.

Comment: I inserted the output xml that we want to get. Could you help us?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a powershell script.  I used Regex and the Net Library Xml Linq.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$filename = "c:\temp\test"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename + '.xml')
$nsV1 = $doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('v1')
$xFilter = $doc.Descendants($nsV1 + 'Filter')
$FilterText = $xFilter.Value
$pattern = '^(?<prefix>ActivityObjectId IN\s+\()(?<array>[^)]+)(?<suffix>.*)'
$FilterText -match $pattern | out-null
$numbers = $Matches.array
$numberArray = $numbers.Split(',')

$fileCounter = 0
for($i = 0; $i -lt $numberArray.Length; $i += 5)
{
   $newNumbers = [string]::Join(',',$numberArray[$i..($i+4)])
   $newFilterText = $Matches.prefix + $newNumbers + $Matches.suffix
   $xFilter.SetValue($newFilterText)
   $fileCounter++
   $doc.Save($filename + $fileCounter + '.xml')
}
```